# Maven + Spring Project Structure Standard

Tags: java, spring, maven, web, structure

Actually I am new in using Maven and Spring, and I am curious on how we standarized the project structure. As we know, if we create Maven project for the first time it only gives this structure:

```
project
   - pom.xml
   - src/
         - main/
               - java/
         - test/
```

The **java** directory is a directory for us to put the java codes, I understand that. But, when we make a web application that should have web files such as HTML, CSS, or Javascript, we need another directory to place it.

When I used Spring or Spring Boot in Maven, it created **resources** directory also under **main** directory. So the structure now looks like this:

```
project
   - pom.xml
   - src/
         - main/
               - java/
               - resources/
         - test/
```

In some other maven web project examples, I found different structure, it had **webapp** directory under **main** also. And inside the **webapp** it had **WEB-INF** and **META-INF** directory. They put web files (HTML, CSS, so on) inside there. The project structure was:

```
project
   - pom.xml
   - src/
         - main/
               - java/
               - resources/
               - webapp/
                     - WEB-INF/
                     - META-INF/
                           - pages/ *contains html pages
                     - static/ * contains css and javascript files for styling
     - test/
```

And this is what I am confused about. I have some questions about this.

1. How do we know it is a best structure or not? Honestly, what is the best structure for maven and spring application?
2. If the structure is like the third example I've given, how do we use it in our application, when calling the asset files?
3. Does WEB-INF and META-INF directory are really needed when we build some web applications?

I will be thankful if someone could give me a clear explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the type of an application.
If you want to make a `JAR` file, Spring-Boot application, for example, when servlet container is embedded, then you don't need the `webapp` directory.

So, the best structure of single Maven project for `JAR` is:

```
project
   - pom.xml
   - src/
          - main/
               - java/
               - resources/
          - test/
               - java/
               - resources/
```

For `WAR`:

```
project
   - pom.xml
   - src/
          - main/
               - java/
               - resources/
               - webapp/
                   - WEB-INF/
                       - web.xml
                   - index.jsp
                   - css/
                       - styles.css
          - test/
               - java/
               - resources/
```

All files under `webapp` (except `WEB-INF/**`) directory will be available thru servlet container.
Also, if you are using template engine and don't want to give an access to the templates files directly, then you should put templates into `WEB-INF/` directory, like: `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/pages/`.

And `META-INF` directory actually is Java meta directory. You should not put anything inside of it.

Comment: So, in other words you mean that it depends on the packaging type? If it's `WAR` or `JAR` it will determine the project structure automatically?

Comment: For example, if I use thymeleaf so I don't need WEB-INF anymore, right? I just put **template** under **resource** directory. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I found something new here. I create maven + spring boot application with thymeleaf as the template engine and WAR for packaging, but it doesn't create any `webapp` directory. I think it's because the `thymeleaf`. Am I correct?

Comment: @IchromanRaditya Packaging type determine what you actually want to get. `WAR` is a web application type and it's located at your `pom.xml` file. And you need `WEB-INF` directory anyway. At least, you have to put `web.xml` file inside of it. Also, your templates have to be inside the WEB-INF/ directory. All files from `webapp` directory (except inner `WEB-INF/**`) will be available directly. If `webapp` directory is missing, just create it.

Comment: @IchromanRaditya If you put file at the `webapp` directory, you could get it like static file. But your templates must be processed by the Template Engine first. That means, that you should not let users fetch your templates as static .html files. That's why you need to put templates files inside the `WEB-INF/` directory. Is it make sense?

Comment: @IchromanRaditya And actually your templates are web content. You should put all files related to front-end to the `webapp` directory. At the `resources` directory you will put properties, configs and etc.

Comment: @IchromanRaditya If you are using Spring-Boot, then I recommend to use `JAR` packaging type. Spring-Boot applications could be packaged as executable `JAR` file, and like a deployable `WAR` file.

Comment: Still don't get it, I'm sorry. I'm trying hard to digest it but it seems hard for me to understand.

I already knew that `resources` is the place to put some files like `application.properties` and so on. When I use create spring boot project with thymeleaf it just make `templates` and `static` directory under `resources` without `webapp` directory. And my app just run as usual.

Here I could sum up that we don't really need webapp or even WEB-INF directory, only if we use another template engine such as **Thymeleaf**, because the engine itself already did the job for directing the view.